# One slider that returns two values

Tags: jquery, uislider

I would like to use jQuery to create one slider that allows two different values to be chosen. I honestly have no idea where to get started.

I'd like for it to display positive values on both sides, but returns two values.

For example:

500----------0----------500

If the slider moves towards the left side, it returns "amount1". If it moves to the right it returns "amount2". Both numbers will be positive. I've toyed with this for hours to no avail.

Here is the sample code that I'm working with. Is this possible?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider({
  value:0,
  min: 500,
  max: 500,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
  }
});
$( "#amount1" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
<label for="amount">Amount</label>
<input type="text" id="amount1" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
<input type="text" id="amount2" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
</p>
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Your example code references an element with id `slider`, but your html contains no element with that id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go about it like this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      value:0,
      min: -500,
      max: 500,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
          if (ui.value > 0){
             $( "#amount1" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
          }else{
               //multiply by -1 to make positive
             $( "#amount2" ).val( "$" + parseInt(ui.value * -1));
          }
      }
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/TrgJR/

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions!

---

EDIT:

Here is a cleaned up version.

Thank you, mrtsherman & Doorknob for your contribution!

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider").slider({
        value: 0,
        min: -500,
        max: 500,
        step: 10,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.value > 0) {
                $("#amount2").val("$" + ui.value);
                $("#amount1").val("");
            } else {
                //multiply by -1 to make positive
                $("#amount1").val("$" + parseInt(ui.value * -1));
                $("#amount2").val("");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/PXDJb/1/

Comment: Nice job. You would want to switch amounts 1 and 2 to correspond with the UI, but it works. Here is a slightly cleaned up fiddle based on your code. Also, just noticed that if you slide back and forth one of the old value gets left in. You should clear it. http://jsfiddle.net/PXDJb/2

Comment: And here's an extra-cleanup for clearing the other value when the first one is changed: http://jsfiddle.net/PXDJb/1/ @Brian This will solve that problem.

Comment: You guys are absolutely incredible! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a similar one here you can find it out http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/

(Or)

Here is another way to do it: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TYyfZ/)**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 1000,
        values: [ 75, 300, ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```